# header is not added to the Get request in HttpClient in angular

Tags: angular, httpclient

i have a fake back-end API and in my code i check the header token. it is my fake back-end code:

```
       if (connection.request.url.endsWith('/api/orders') &&
       connection.request.method === RequestMethod.Get) {
       if (connection.request.headers.get('Authorization') === 'Bearer ' 
         + token) {
          connection.mockRespond(new Response(
          new ResponseOptions({ status: 200, body: [1, 2, 3] })
         ));
       } else {
         connection.mockRespond(new Response(
          new ResponseOptions({ status: 401 })
        ));
     }
```

and in my service i have a GET method which add the header to the request to fetch the data.

getOrders() {

```
let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
let headers = new HttpHeaders()
headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
return this.http.get('/api/orders' , {headers:headers} ).subscribe(result=>{
  console.log('result : ' , result);
});
```

}

but, i get nothing and the result is empty. the status code is 401 and i can not get the data according to the header. how can i solve the problem?

Comment: I doubt the header is not added to the request. Open your browser dev tools, go to the network panel, use your app to send the request, then find the request in the network panel, inspect its headers. Check that the token is there and has the expected value.

Comment: the header is not added. but i do the code correct, am i right?

Comment: Your code seems right. Are you sure the token is filled in localStorage?

Comment: yes. i see the token in the local storage

Comment: Could you check in Network to check if request has `Authorization` header even if it's empty, Or It never shown?

Comment: it never shows the Authorization  in the network devTools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally find my answer. in Angular 7, the best way to add header to the request is, using the interceptor. in the interceptors, you can add header to the request and as a result, you can access to the protected API. here is the interceptor sample which adds header to the request :

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
let currentUser = this.authservice.currentUser;
if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
    request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
        }
    });
}

return next.handle(request)
```